# Can't scp to Azure's VM

Tags: linux, azure, ssh, virtual-machine, scp

I'm trying to copy some files from my machine to an Azure VM. I say in advance that I can ssh the Azure's VM, I gave my public key during the creation of the machine. Both machines are Linux.

When I try:

`sudo scp /path/ca.crt ubuntu@ip.add.res.s:~/`

I receive in output:

`Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection`

I'm not pointing on a root directory (my file is in a root directory that's why the sudo); I'm not pointing to a wrong user; if I can connect through ssh why scp should be denied?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `sudo` to access a root file, `scp` is going to look for the identity file `id_rsa` in `/root/.ssh/` instead of in `/home/user/.ssh/`. That's why I have to specify **the identity file** in the scp command (**not the public key**):

`sudo scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa /path/ca.crt ubuntu@ip.add.res.s:/home/ubuntu/`

I hope that this can be useful to someone else.

Cheers.

Comment: `scp` will use `~/.ssh/id_rsa` by default. I think if you don't use `-i ` will the same result. What other you change?

Comment: @Walter-MSFT nothing more, just that. Using `scp -v -v -v` I noticed that (obviusly) using sudo it was going to look for the id_rsa file in `/root/.ssh/` instead of in `/home/user/.ssh/`, that's why I have to specify the correct path (shame on me).

Comment: I know the reason, very good answer. I think you had better add it to your answer.

Comment: This plus [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/347412) helped me resolve my issue.

Comment: I fixed it by giving permissions to write to the remote destination folder from VM: `chmod 777 _remote-destination-folder-vm_`