# Scp connection timed out ubuntu VM

Tags: azure, ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machine, scp

so i'm trying to copy a file for my directory to Azure ubuntu VM , SSH works just fine ,but scp command takes a lot of time and then i had this message

```
connect to host 10.x.x.x port 22: Connection timed out lost connection
```

this is the command i used :

```
scp -vvv -i .ssh/id_rsa BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem azureuser@10.x.x.x:/var/www/html
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [ubuntu.se], [unix.se], or [su].

Comment: Hi @Hello_world, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0):

•   AFAIK, **the SCP command that you are using to try to connect to your Ubuntu Azure VM might not be correct** as the correct command to connect to your Ubuntu Linux VM from your local machine to copy files between them is as follows: -

```
 scp -r ./tmp/ azureuser@10.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/file/user/local
```

In the above command, the `SCP connection gets established successfully after entering the private key further which files in the local system in ‘/tmp’ directory is recursively getting copied in the Azure ubuntu VM specified in ‘/home/file/user/local’ directory`. Thus, the whole directory tree as specified is copied from the local system to the Azure ubuntu VM.

•   Also, if you want to use the **private key in the ‘SCP’ command through SSH**, then you will have to use the below command to copy files from the local system to the Azure ubuntu VM: -

```
sudo scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa /path/cert.pem azureuser@10.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/file/user/local
```

Using **‘sudo’** to access a **‘root’** file, while `‘SCP’ is going to look for the identity file ‘id_rsa’ in ‘/root/.ssh/’ instead of in ‘/home/user/.ssh/’. That's why you will have to specify the identity file (private key) in the SCP command to connect to the Azure ubuntu VM and transfer files from local system to the VM`.

Other than this, kindly `ensure that port 22 is opened in the inbound NSG rule on the Azure ubuntu VM and the VM's default page is accessible on port 80/443 over public IP address and the Azure FQDN assigned`.

For more information, kindly refer to the links below: -

[Can't scp to Azure's VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630112/cant-scp-to-azures-vm)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/copy-files-to-linux-vm-using-scp#scp-a-directory-from-a-linux-vm